# how to set Notification Button to Icon instead of words

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-notifications

This is my code so far on understanding notification.

```
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        Intent gIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(GameMenu));
        Intent sIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(SceneMenu));

        PendingIntent mainIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, mIntent, 0);
        PendingIntent gameIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, gIntent, 0);
        PendingIntent sceneIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, sIntent, 0);
        var notifSound = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);

        //long[] pattern = new long[] { 1000, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 500, 500, 1000};

        Notification n = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .SetContentTitle("RBOS Notification")
                .SetContentText("You won $1million")
                .SetColor(Color.LightGreen)
                //.SetVibrate(pattern)
                .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.Max)
                .SetShowWhen(true)
                .SetSound(notifSound)
                //.SetTicker(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mmtt"))
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_fb)
                .SetContentIntent(mainIntent)
                .SetAutoCancel(false)
                .SetLights(Color.Green, 1000, 1000)
                .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.ic_main, "Main", mainIntent)
                .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.ic_play, "Game", gameIntent)
                .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.ic_scene, "Scene", sceneIntent).Build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
          (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);

        notificationManager.Notify(0, n);
```

I am a bit confused on how to set the icon itself for notification rather than words. target api is jellybean to higher.
on my phone Asus with nougat OS, it only display words. In other phone Starmobile and OPPO, it display the icons but with only part of words. I want to display something like radio notif or vlc player notif with previous play/pause next icon buttons alone (without its words).

And for side question. What is the use of ticker? I can't see any changes when I put it there. Also in OPPO, why notification didn't appear instantly (like when battery is low) even priority set in max

Answer (score 1):

Standard notifications will appear different on the various APIs (and even different among the same API level but different OEMs).

It seems you want to create a `RemoteViews` and use it as your notification's `CustomContentView` (like a media player in the notification drawer). That way you can override the default notification template using your own layout and content.

#### Example:

```
var remoteView = new RemoteViews(PackageName, Resource.Layout.Alarm);
remoteView.SetInt(Resource.Id.myButton, "setText", Resource.String.rocks);

var notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                   .SetSmallIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogInfo)
                   .SetCustomContentView(remoteView)
                   .Build();
```

The `Resource.Layout.Alarm` layout contains just one `Button`, thus the notification is just one button across the notification drawer:

[image]